# When is log-loss metric appropriate for evaluating performance of a classifier?

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, scoring-rules

Specifically, for which model classes and under which circumstances is it reasonable to tune the classifier to optimize the log-loss rate?

Answer (score 7):

Log-loss is an appropriate performance measure when you're model output is the probability of a binary outcome.

The log-loss measure considers confidence of the prediction when assessing how to penalize incorrect classification. For instance consider two predictions of an outcome P(Y=1|X), where the predictions are 0.51 and 0.99 respectively. In the former case the model is only slightly confident of the class prediction (assuming a 0.5 cutoff), while in the latter it is extremely confident. Since in our case both are wrong, the penalty will be more harsh for the more confident (but incorrect) prediction by employing a log-loss penalty.

Comment: It's not clear how this relates to taking the log.  Mean absolute error would also have this property, for instance.

Comment: @dsaxton have a look at [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/understand-classification-machine-learning/4-assess-classification#:~:text=the%20graph%20readable.-,Why%20not%20MSE%3F,-MSE%20and%20log)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a good probability estimate that punishes extreme values when these are wrong, then logloss can do that.

Read more on [Making Sense of Logarithmic Loss](http://www.r-bloggers.com/making-sense-of-logarithmic-loss/).

> Log Loss heavily penalises classifiers that are confident about an
>   incorrect classification. For example, if for a particular
>   observation, the classifier assigns a very small probability to the
>   correct class then the corresponding contribution to the Log Loss will
>   be very large indeed. Naturally this is going to have a significant
>   impact on the overall Log Loss for the classifier. The bottom line is
>   that it’s better to be somewhat wrong than emphatically wrong. Of
>   course it’s always better to be completely right, but that is seldom
>   achievable in practice!

Comment: The reference is very valuable, alas, no picture is showing.