# Does "Log loss" refer to Logarithmic loss or Logistic loss?

Tags: logistic, terminology, logarithm, loss-functions

I know I've seen it both ways, so is there a difference between the two, and which one is more commonly referred to?

Comment: What is the context in which this phrase was used? Where did you see this?

Answer (score 17):

Logarithmic loss = Logistic loss = log loss = $-y_i\log(p_i) - (1 -y_i) \log(1 -p_i)$

Sometimes people take a different logarithmic base, but it typically doesn't matter. I hear logistic loss more often.

---

FYI:

- [How is logistic loss and cross-entropy related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1074276/24265)
- [Thesaurus for statistics and machine learning terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/96161/12359)
- [When is log-loss metric appropriate for evaluating performance of a classifier?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/180116/12359)
- [Multi-class logarithmic loss function per class](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/113301/12359)